# Selenium (Java) and trouble getting Select element

Tags: java, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble getting and using a Select element using @FindBy.

The markkup:

```
<td>
   <felt [control]="kontactTypeFC" [classes]="'hb-distNone'">
      <label for="contactTypes" class="hb-label">Kontakttype</label>
      <select formControlName="contactType" class="hb-inputfield" id="contactTypes" [attr.disabled]="erSakenLukket(sak)">
         <option *ngFor="let option of contactTypeOptions" [ngValue]="option.type" [disabled]="option.disabled"> {{option.text }} </option>
      </select>
   </felt>
</td>
```

The following selenium code works fine

```
return new Select(this.element.findElement(By.id("contactTypes")));
```

However, this does not:

```
@FindBy(id = "contactTypes")
public Select contactTypes;

return contactTypes;
```

This returns null, creating an NPE.

I'm using the exact same method for getting other elements on the page. Only difference is that the other elements are WebElement, not Select.

NB: I am of course initializing the page object:

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` is a class which receives `WebElement` in the constructor, you can't use page factory to initialize it. Locate the `WebElement` with `@FindBy` and use it with the `Select`

```
@FindBy(id = "contactTypes")
public WebElement contactTypes;

new Select(contactTypes);
```